# Function such that $f''(x) f(x)-(f'(x))^2 \ge 0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, inequality

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^+$ be a non-negative twice differentiable function such that:
$$f''(x)f(x)-(f'(x))^2 \ge 0, \qquad a \le x \le b.$$
How to prove that if $f$ vanishes in some point $x_0 \in [a,b]$ then it vanishes in the whole interval $[a,b]$?

If we assume that $f(x_0)=0$ the inequality implies that $f'(x_0)=0$, but I don't know how to complete the proof.

Comment: @CalvinLin you get $f''(x_0) \times 0 \geq [f'(x_0)] ^2$ !

Comment: yea, mis-read.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume that $f(x_0) = 0$ for some $x_0$ but $f$ is not identically zero. Then there is an interval $[c, d] \subset [a, b]$ such that $f(x) \ne 0$ on $(c, d)$ and $f(c) = 0$ or $f(d) = 0$.

Now consider $g(x) = \log f(x)$ on the open interval $(c, d)$. 
$$
 g'(x) = \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \\
 g''(x) = \frac{f''(x) f(x)- f'(x)^2}{f(x)^2} \ge 0
$$
so that $g$ is *convex.* Choose any $e \in (c, d)$. Then
$$
 g(x) \ge g(e) + (x-e)g'(e) \implies f(x) \ge e^{g(e) + (x-e)g'(e)}
$$
for all $x \in (c, d)$, contradicting the assumption that $f(x)$ is zero at one of the boundary points of the interval.

Comment: Thank you! just how there is $(c,d)$ s.t $f(c)=0$ or $f(d)=0$?

Comment: @Sigma: If $f(x_1) \ne 0$ then choose $c$ as the “largest zero” in $[a, x_1]$ or $d$ as the “smallest zero” in $[x_1, d]$. One of them must exist if $f$ has a zero in the interval.